# Port ListShuttle component from RichFaces to PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

We are using an application with primefaces 4 with JBoss EAP 6.1. One of the screens need a [listshuttle](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/listShuttle.jsf?tab=usage&cid=291074) component which is not available in primefaces but available in rich faces.

Is there an easy way to create the custom component using reference of rich faces implementation or any other work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a PrimeFaces component that works like a listshuttle: the pickList.

I am aware that the showcase is for 5.0, however, I worked on a project that used PF 4.0 and we had a few pickLists.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

It's customizeable in its interface (check the PickList on steroids section), and in its actions via the onTransfer method. Cheers.